# Append text to jQuery first after progress is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, settimeout

**Problem:**

Appending text to a div after the progress bar is completed but before setTimeout() is initiated.

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="loading" class="files"></div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script>    
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Server-side upload handler:
        var url = 'process.php';

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
            done: function (e, data) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location = "explorer.php";}, 2000);
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
</script>
```

**Desired outcome:**

Once the progress bar is 100%, append text "Loading ..." to the div and then initiate setTimeout().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The done method should have the code to do this. So your done would become,

```
progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
                if (progress == 100)
                    $("#loading").html("Loading...");
            }
```

But the text "Loading..." would be shown to the user only for few seconds as we have initiated a page refresh after 2 seconds.

Comment: Tried this solution but the text would appear directly while the progress is building up. I'm wondering if it's possible to have a delay between the text and progress?

Comment: Then we can add the code in progressall function. I have edited the code above.